# Jquery tag input adding some character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with jquery tag input but when I create some tag, the tag automatically include some random character.

Below is the screenshot of the tag input box

[Link of image](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/186294/4181db912925183d23b17505b4dc6ef0)

I don't know  how to get rid of it.. I searched on google they give me solution to add some meta tag and I also added some meta like this

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

this is the plugin [Link](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) which i am using

this is the html code

```
<input id="expert_tags" name="spl_tags" type="text" class="form-control tags" value=""/>
```

this is javascript code

```
$('#expert_tags').tagsInput({});
```

thats it only that much of code for tag input

Comment: Show the code which you are using.

Comment: What does `tagsInput` do? Can you show the full code please? (Oh, my bad, I see it's a plugin). Are you entering any non-ascii style characters after "sanji" that may be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

If you are getting the tags via ajax you should check if the header is set on the server side. In PHP it would look something like this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: i already mention in my question i used meta tag but its not working